# Solr: how do I use dismax instead of using copyField?

Tags: solr, dismax

I've been trying to figure this out for a bit now.  If I create a schema without the directive:

```
<copyField source="*" dest="text" />
```

I can't seem to pull anything up.  But when I add that directive, things magically appear.  I'm trying my query with ?defType=dismax, but that doesn't seem to help.

Am I missing something?  Do I need something special in my schema?  I'm indexing all the fields I need to search against.

Thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use defType=lucene you need to specify the field before your search query like this:

```
q=title:test
```

If you don't specify a field solr will use the default field specified in `solrconfig.xml`. This field is `text` by default. As all the fields are copied to `text` the search works well.
If you decide to use `dismax` the query structure changes. You need to put your search term like that:

```
q=test
```

and specify the fields to search in other parameter like that:

```
<str name="qf">field1 field2</str>
```

Where `field1` and `field2` are the fields you want to search the terms.